# Do I need to install access runtime when MS Office is already installed on the client PC

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, ms-access, ms-office

I developed a simple c# wpf application that is importing an excel-file to an accdb-file.

The client has Office 2016 installed (including MS Access).

I was using for the connection String "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0...." and I get the error message that OLEDB.16.0 is not registered on the local machine.
The solution would be to install the corresponding ms access runtime but the client is not allowed to install it (because of missing admin rights).

I guess I did something wrong because **in my opinion you don't need to install the access runtime when MS Office + MS Access is already installed on the client's PC. *Am I right or not*?**

Thanks for your short feedback

Comment: No, you don't. The runtimes and viewers are for computers that do not have current versions installed. Depending on the installation (not everyone installs with 'run everything from this computer') you might have to install a driver pack.

Comment: Check whether you have a 32-/64-bit mismatch. E.g. your C# WPF app is 64-bit and the Office installation is 32-bit or vice versa. This will not work; bitness must be the same.

Comment: I build the appliction in 32 and 64 bit and office 2016 + access 2016 is installed, still the message oledb.12 / 15 / 16 whatever is not registered... :/ any further ideas

Comment: Call "regedit", open HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT key and check whether there are keys starting with "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.". If no, then they are really not registered.

Comment: Hey @FrankM thx, yes i can approve that they are not registered in "regedit" but the question is why?

Comment: I was once cursed by working with Access db, after I restrained myself from cutting my wrists I found that the runtime was needed if you use the apps and also the database. Don't worry once you stop working with Access you will see the light :-)